# How to Deserialize prpBytes(Link src in description) (ProposalResponsePayload protobuf message) to object original

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a question regarding a method in `plugin.go`, found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/handlers/endorsement/plugin/plugin.go#L42) within the Hyperledger fabric library.

```
// Endorse signs the given payload(ProposalResponsePayload bytes), and optionally mutates it.
// Returns:
// The Endorsement: A signature over the payload, and an identity that is used to verify the signature
// The payload that was given as input (could be modified within this function)
// Or error on failure
func (e *DefaultEndorsement) Endorse(prpBytes []byte, sp *peer.SignedProposal) (*peer.Endorsement, []byte, error) {
    signer, err := e.SigningIdentityForRequest(sp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("failed fetching signing identity: %v", err))
    }
    // serialize the signing identity
    identityBytes, err := signer.Serialize()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("could not serialize the signing identity: %v", err))
    }

    // sign the concatenation of the proposal response and the serialized endorser identity with this endorser's key
    signature, err := signer.Sign(append(prpBytes, identityBytes...))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("could not sign the proposal response payload: %v", err))
    }
    endorsement := &peer.Endorsement{Signature: signature, Endorser: identityBytes}
    return endorsement, prpBytes, nil
}
```

How can I deserialize the argument `prpBytes` to the object original?

`prpBytes` is type `ProposalResponsePayload protobuf message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import 
  (
      "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/rwsetutil"

  )

prp := &peer.ProposalResponsePayload{}
proto.Unmarshal(prpBytes, prp)

chaincodeAction := &peer.ChaincodeAction{}
proto.Unmarshal(prp.Extension, chaincodeAction)

fmt.Println(chaincodeAction.Response)
txRWSet := &rwsetutil.TxRwSet{}
txRWSet.FromProtoBytes(chaincodeAction.Results)
for _, ns := range txRWSet.NsRwSets {
    fmt.Println("chaincode:", ns.NameSpace)
    for _, rws := range ns.KvRwSet.Reads {
        fmt.Println("read key", rws.Key)
    }

    for _, rws := range ns.KvRwSet.Writes {
        fmt.Println("wrote", string(rws.Value), "to key", rws.Key)
    }
}
```